# From Office 2003 to Office 2010

Tags: office-2010

I installed Office 2010 and I would like to know if there is a trick to convert all files (.doc in .docx, etc)

Comment: The old binary format is still supported in all future versions of Office and there are no downsides for still using it if you only rely on older features. If you use newer ones when editing the files, they’ll be automatically saved as XML based files.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so clear why would you want to do that. Office 2010 has a backward compatibility and it and will have no problem reading your `.doc` files. If you just want to convert these files to `.docx` format, you can just open them in Office 2010 and use the `Save As..` option.

Comment: I thought it was mendatory